# DropDownList.Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть 2 системы. Тестовая и продуктивная. И в дроп даун лист записывается значение на обоих системах абсолютно одинаково.

```
ddlZatochReas1.Value = CharsVal["Причина заточки 1"].ToString();
```

Значения идут одинаковые. Проверял. Только на тестовой всё идёт нормально. А на продуктивной после этой строчки. Value у дроп дауна остаётся таким же каким и было. То есть не перезаписывается. Как такое может быть? Есть у дроп даунов какое нибудь свойство что бы запрещать перезапись?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убедись, что это значение представлено в списке всех возможных значений DropDownList. Value не может указывать на несуществующий элемент списка.